# Excel Formula - Conditional - Highlight Cell if Char Count > 160

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

Apparently Stackoverflow does allow question on excel formulas, so I will give this a shot. Hopefully I'm not down voted too quickly.

I'm creating an excel file, on one column I am expecting user input. This column "should" have a max-char count of 160.  I want this cell highlight if the user input is greater than this amount.

**JS Pseudo Example:**

```
var x = $(this).val().length;

if(x>160){
 $(this).css("background","red");
}
```

Comment: Use [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9) directly on the cell in question. The custom validation formula would be `=Len(A1)<161`, where A1 is the cell in question. Then you can copy the validation down as many rows in the column you need. The difference here is that you are *not allowing* entry unless it's less than 161 characters. To highlight use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-FED60DFA-1D3F-4E13-9ECB-F1951FF89D7F)

Comment: To highlight it, you can use Conditional Formatting, with the reverse of @Scott's formula -- `=LEN(A1)>160`

Answer (score 1):

Select the relevant column and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=LEN(
```

enter the reference to your mystery column

```
1)>160
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

However, as noted by @Scott Holtzman, where convenient it is generally better to block bad data than to accept and highlight it.

Comment: It is nice to see you back.  Been a while.